# Filling a matrix in a numpythonic way

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a L x L matrix A, which I currently fill in using the following code:

```
A = np.zeros((L, L))
for J in range(X):
  for a in range(L):
    for b in range(L):
      A[a][b] += alpha[J, a] * O[b, J] * A_old[a, b] * betas[J+2, b]
```

Where X is an integer defined elsewhere, `alpha` and `betas` is of shape `(X, L)`, O is of shape `(L, X)` and A_old is of shape `(L, L)`. I'm concerned about the speed of this code, and am trying to find a more numpythonic way to approach filling in this matrix. My instinct is to do something like:

```
for J in range(X):
   A += alpha[J, :] * O[:, J] * A_old[:, :] * betas[J+2, :]
```

But this doesn't broadcast the operations correctly because of the A_old matrix (the resulting shape is right, but the values are not). What's a good way to condense this loop using numpy?

Comment: What are the dimensions of `alpha`, `O`, `A_old`, and `betas`? Are `j` and `J` different or is there a typo? Can you please provide a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @ramzeek Typo is corrected. Will add dimensions to the post, I guess the MRE would be initializing those matrices to ones and running the above code

Comment: The `alpha[J, a] * O[b, J] ` part looks a lot like a matrix product, `np.dot(O,alpha)`.  `betas[J+2, b]` is `betas[2:,:][J,b]`.  It may be useful to write this as a `np.einsum`.